# Ember defineProperty not reflecting on template until notifyProperty change is called?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, frontend, ember-cli, computed-properties

I basically have a feature flag which gets added into a list on user saving a configuration. On save I create a computed property on a service object as showing below.

```
//classify() just removes the '_' and Makes it title case 'add_location' --> 'AddLocation'
      defineFeature(feature) {
        defineProperty(this, `is${classify(feature)}`, computed('session.account.features.[]', 
         function() {
          return this.hasFeature(feature);
        }));
      },
```

Now this sets the property on the service object and I consume it in my .hbs file. However it does not reflect unless I trigger `<serviceObj>.notifyPropertyChange('is<FlagName');`

I am confused why Ember doesn't update by itself or am I doing something wrong?

Adding more context

My handlerbar file

```
{{#if featureService.isAddLocation}}
  <span>User can now add locations for this account</span>
{{/if}}
```

Component File

A save function which basically toggles the flag.

```
onSave() {
 // This method is called on user action
 let account = get(this, 'account');
 account.enableSaveLocation().then(() => {
   account.reload().then(() => {
     // basically only after the save the feature 'add_location' gets added to
    // the features array in the 'account' model
    featureService.defineFeature('add_location');
    //featureService.notifyPropertyChange('isAddLocation'); // Without this line the template doesnt reflect the change
   }) 
 })
}
```

Ember: v3.4

Comment: Phew... any chance on getting more context or better a twiddle?

Comment: Hi Andrey, sorry for being vague. I have added a few more lines of code for context. Please let me know if that was clear else need to figure out a way to create a twiddle. Appreciate the response

Comment: I suspect it is because the property does not exist until after the template is rendered, so Ember does not have a mechanism to trigger the update. If it were rendering an existing computed property then it would get notified automatically when the computed property changed.

Comment: Yes Vadim I agree on that, my initially understanding of the behaviour was the same, but am I just curious why Ember is not able to watch this change or is this expected behaviour under the hood.

Comment: I think your primary problem here is that basically `defineProperty` with a computed property is not a supported/documented feature. Also with ember 3.13+ `tracked-built-ins` will probably be the way to go.

Comment: Oh okay Lux, well its far down the road before our project is migrated to newer versions of ember. Raised this question to improve my understanding. Thank you all for the contribution Andrey/Vladimir and Lux

Comment: I believe we should define the computed property before pushing the `add_location` to the features array. Right now, it looks like you are trying to define the CP after pushing it.